# How can I hidden a link after displaying the content hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how can I hidden the link/button “Link with href” when someone click on it. Which displays a new div with text ( "Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim ...!)

Please find the example here http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#example

I have tried to copy and past the Bootstrap example here but for some reason it doesn't work correctly with the snippet.

Thanks

Andres

Comment: the easiest way would be just add a `onClick="$(this).hide()"` to it. This supposing you are using jQuery, or any native javascript that would set the `display: none`

Comment: Could you provide us with a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straightforward single-line function in both native javascript and jQuery.

**Javascript:**

The native javascript gives the button a new `display:` style:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

function hideButton() {
    button.style.display = 'none';
}

button.addEventListener('click', hideButton, false);
```

```html
<button type="button">Link with href</button>
```

**jQuery:**

The jQuery library uses a proprietary jQuery method: `hide()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).hide()});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Link with href</button>
```

Comment: Thank you.! :) It is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear what you want to accomplish, but if you want the same effect like the bootstrap example, you could do something like this:

(Uses jQuery)

```js
$("a.slide").click(function () {
  $("div.toggle-slide").slideToggle();
});

// or use fade

$("a.fade").click(function () {
  $("div.toggle-fade").fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a href="#" class="slide">Toggle Element(slide)</a>

  <div class="toggle-slide" style="display:none">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--  Or use fade -->

<div>
  <a href="#" class="fade">Toggle Element (fade)</a>

  <div class="toggle-fade" style="display:none">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply guys.